# Why dont my linear layout view gets displayed when i run my app

Tags: android

i have already created my xml file in which 4 layouts are used. now i want a linear layout to be displayed between my 3rd and fourth layout.i have set the width of this new layout to 0dp, for which i want the width to be changed to "wrap content" when my app is launched.

i have tried using the following code

```
LinearLayout  layout = (LinearLayout)base.findViewById(R.id.layout);    
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
    Log.w(TAG, "layout " +layout);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

following is my layout in xml file

```
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_height="0dp"
    >
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="NO" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="YES"

        android:layout_marginRight="50dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

but the layout value takes here as null.. Can anyone tell me how this can be solved..???
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please show: 1) the XML file where ID `layout` is defined and 2) how you load `base`.

Comment: the base is used as a view in my method where this part of code is written..

Comment: After re-reading your question again, couldn't you start out with the total of 5 layouts and set the one between 3rd and 4th `visibility="gone"` in your XML -- if you then want to show it, just set `visibility="visible"`. This way you don't need to do anything with the size/layout params.

Comment: Need more information. Xml file needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing the android schema and the height amount. Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    >
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="NO" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="YES"

        android:layout_marginRight="50dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you have provided height as "0dip" here. **android:layout_height="0dp"**.

Try to change it to "**wrap_content**" and try.